# What does it mean "Another object with the same value for property proxyAddresses already exists" during licensing an user in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API versin 1.0 to update a batch of user and for some I receive the following error message:

```
Another object with the same value for property proxyAddresses already exists.
```

This happens with some few user, but not with many others.

However I don't understand what it means and how to workaround it.

Any ideas?

### Update1:

This my the JSON payload sent with the request:

```
{
    "addLicenses":[
     {
         "disabledPlans": [
             "76846ad7-7776-4c40-a281-a386362dd1b9",
             "54fc630f-5a40-48ee-8965-af0503c1386e",
             "c68f8d98-5534-41c8-bf36-22fa496fa792",
             "8c7d2df8-86f0-4902-b2ed-a0458298f3b3",
             "9e700747-8b1d-45e5-ab8d-ef187ceec156",
             "c87f142c-d1e9-4363-8630-aaea9c4d9ae5",
             "b8afc642-032e-4de5-8c0a-507a7bba7e5d",
             "2078e8df-cff6-4290-98cb-5408261a760a"
         ],
         "skuId":"94763226-9b3c-4e75-a931-5c89701abe66"
     }],
     "removeLicenses":[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, the property `proxyAddresses` should be unique.

Please make sure you don't configure the same `proxyAddresses` for multiple users when updating users.

In theory, this property cannot be updated through the Microsoft Graph API. So if you didn't put `proxyAddresses` in the body, please share the requests of the updated users which have this issue.

Comment: I dont have any proxyAddress property in my JSON payload

Comment: It is strange. Depending on the body content, your updates to the user are limited to disabling the license instead of making changes to the ```proxyAddresses```. Are you using batch updates:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching or making an update for each user? I need more details to try to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

this may be old, I encountered a similar issue. I am doing a graph api call which indirectly updates some of user attributes, so getting this error. The tenant admin should check for duplicate records and remove or update them, they can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/active-directory/duplicate-attributes-prevent-dirsync)